# What is the cardinality of $A=\{f\colon \omega_n \to \omega_m | |\operatorname{Supp}(f)|=\aleph_k \quad k<n\}?$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I'm trying to compute the cardinality of a determined set.
$A=\{f\colon \omega_n \to \omega_m | |\operatorname{Supp}(f)|=\aleph_k \quad k<n\}.$

As suggested by the exercise, I first tried few elementar cases:
$A_1=\{f\colon \omega \to \omega | |\operatorname{Supp}|<\aleph_0\}$.

It's easy to see that $|A_1|=\aleph_0$ as it is a countable union of countable sets.

Another case:

$A_2=\{f\colon \omega_1 \to \omega | |\operatorname{Supp}(f)|=\aleph_0\}$.
For this I started having few difficulties, but I think I figured out the solution:
$\phi:A_2 \to [\omega_1]^{\aleph_0} \times Fun(Supp(f),\omega)
\\ f \mapsto (Supp(f), f|_{Supp(f)})$,
is a bijection so we have that $|A_2|=|[\omega_1]^{\aleph_0} \times Fun(Supp(f),\omega)|=2^{\aleph_0}$

So, by using the same argument i want to say that
$$\phi:A_2 \to [\omega_n]^{\aleph_k} \times Fun(\operatorname{Supp}(f),\omega_m)
\\ f \mapsto (Supp(f), f|_{Supp(f)})$$
is a bijection so $|A|=|[\omega_n]^{\aleph_k} \times Fun(\operatorname{Supp},\omega_m)| = max(2^{\aleph_k},\aleph_n, \aleph_m^{\aleph_k})$.

Is my proof true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that this is just $\aleph_n^{<\aleph_n}=\aleph_n^{\aleph_{n-1}}$. Set $m=n-1$, then we have $\aleph_{m+1}^{\aleph_m}$. Then compute this as $2^{\aleph_m}$.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to say.

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci: probably $$2^{\aleph_m}\leq \aleph_{m+1}^{\aleph_m}\leq 2^{\aleph_m*\aleph_m}$$